# What is a good charting library for Java to make a 3D scatterplot and sphere/shape objects?

Tags: java, 3d, charts, netbeans7.0

We are going to add a 3D chart to our project that will graph 3D data points and hopefully the calculated sphere of best fit. We are looking for one that is compatible with Swing (i.e., we can add it to a Jpanel), can plot a collection of X,Y,Z points, and allows the user to rotate the chart.

It would be nice to have the ability to plot a sphere or an ellipsoid. It would also be great to have 3D acceleration. And a library that has high performance when plotting points in real time would be optimal.

Right now, we're thinking [Jzy3D](http://code.google.com/p/jzy3d/). Or [JMathPlot](http://code.google.com/p/jmathplot/), which works very well, but seems to use pseudo-3D.

Libraries that aren't acceptable (thus far): those without 3D points (JFreeChart, JChart2D).

Comment: Just a thought, but switch from Netbeans to Eclipse. While Netbeans can be nice, Eclipse is far more main-stream.

Comment: how about jfreechart? http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/

Comment: From what I hear, JFreeChart only does 3D visualizations, not true 3D graphing. Also, in our experiences with JFreeChart, it doesn't handle real-time data too well. We ran the same charts in JFreeChart and JChart2D and JFreeChart require twice the processing power with the same settings.

Comment: As for why we aren't using Eclipse, we've already extensively used the Netbeans API, and I'm not telling my boss to redo all his code simply to add a 3D chart.

Comment: Jzy3d has also the great advantage of using open gl to render and is much more faster than libraries such as JFreeChart that use java2d for drawing dense charts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have Jzy3d working with NetBeans, you have to instanciate a Swing chart, as explained here:

[Is it possible to use Jzy3D in a Netbeans 7.0 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494668/is-it-possible-to-use-jzy3d-in-a-netbeans-7-0-application)

Cheers,

Martin

Comment: Yeah, I got it working thanks to your answer, I just forgot to update this. It looks like I will probably be using Jzy3D, because I haven't found anything else that rivals it.